# Azure media Service Stitching Landscape and portrait videos

Tags: azure, azure-media-services

Im trying to stitch together 2 videos, the lead video being landscape and the second being portrait.
However Azure flips the portrait video sideways automatic. is there a way to stop this behaviour? and have the portrait part have black bars to make up the aspect ratio.

The second video is user generated so i have no control as to what size or orientation it will be.

**Update 1:**

Pre processing the Portrait video through the media service and then stitching the resulting file seems to work. but that makes it a 2 step operation. is there a faster way or is that the solution?

**Update 2:**
Yes the ones that are flipped are from smartphones
XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<Preset
  Version="4.0">
  <Job />
  <MediaFile
    DeinterlaceMode="AutoPixelAdaptive"
    ResizeQuality="Super"
    NormalizeAudio="True"
    AudioGainLevel="1"
    VideoResizeMode="Stretch">
    <Sources>
      <Source>
      </Source>
      <Source
       MediaFile="%1%">
      </Source>
    </Sources>
    <OutputFormat>
      <MP4OutputFormat
        StreamCompatibility="Standard">
        <AudioProfile Condition="SourceContainsAudio">
          <AacAudioProfile
            Codec="AAC"
            Channels="2"
            BitsPerSample="16"
            SamplesPerSecond="44100">
            <Bitrate>
              <ConstantBitrate
                Bitrate="128"
                IsTwoPass="False"
                BufferWindow="00:00:00" />
            </Bitrate>
          </AacAudioProfile>
        </AudioProfile>
        <VideoProfile Condition="SourceContainsVideo">
          <MainH264VideoProfile
            BFrameCount="3"
            EntropyMode="Cabac"
            RDOptimizationMode="Quality"
            HadamardTransform="True"
            SubBlockMotionSearchMode="Quality"
            MultiReferenceMotionSearchMode="Quality"
            ReferenceBFrames="False"
            AdaptiveBFrames="True"
            SceneChangeDetector="True"
            FastIntraDecisions="False"
            FastInterDecisions="False"
            SubPixelMode="Quarter"
            SliceCount="0"
            KeyFrameDistance="00:00:05"
            InLoopFilter="True"
            MEPartitionLevel="EightByEight"
            ReferenceFrames="4"
            SearchRange="128"
            AutoFit="True"
            Force16Pixels="False"
            FrameRate="0"
            SeparateFilesPerStream="True"
            SmoothStreaming="False"
            NumberOfEncoderThreads="0">
            <Streams
              AutoSize="False">
              <StreamInfo
                Size="1280, 720">
                <Bitrate>
                  <ConstantBitrate
                    Bitrate="4500"
                    IsTwoPass="False"
                    BufferWindow="00:00:05" />
                </Bitrate>
              </StreamInfo>
            </Streams>
          </MainH264VideoProfile>
        </VideoProfile>
      </MP4OutputFormat>
    </OutputFormat>
  </MediaFile>
</Preset>
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you please try updating your preset as follows:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
    <Presets Rotation="Auto">
        <Preset
          Version="5.0">
          ...
        </Preset>
    </Presets>
```